# Highlight a Row when click on it and leave highlighted when i move to the next row

Tags: excel, vba

I work a lot with large Excel sheet and would highlight the row as i go along in green to indicate completed.
How do i write a macro to do this for me? I plan to later assign this macro to a button

[I want to achieve something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUMsf.png)

I am using the latest version of Excel. Below the what i have tried so far from a video i watched.

[Code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwzrJ.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and copy and paste your code *as text*.  Please see [ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: did you want like this? `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Selection.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
End Sub`